# SQLite Schema Information Metadata

Tags: sqlite, information-schema

I need to get column names and their tables in a SQLite database. What I need is a resultset with 2 columns: `table_name | column_name`.

In MySQL, I'm able to get this information with a SQL query on database `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. However the SQLite offers table `sqlite_master`:

```
sqlite> create table students (id INTEGER, name TEXT);
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
  table|students|students|2|CREATE TABLE students (id INTEGER, name TEXT)
```

which results a DDL construction query (`CREATE TABLE`) which is not helpful for me and I need to parse this to get relevant information.

I need to get list of tables and join them with columns or just get columns along with table name column. So `PRAGMA table_info(TABLENAME)` is not working for me since I don't have table name. I want to get all column metadata in the database.

Is there a better way to get that information as a result set by querying database?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You've basically named the solution in your question.

To get a list of tables (and views), query sqlite_master as in

```
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table'
ORDER BY name;
```

(see [the SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7))

To get information about the columns in a specific table, use `PRAGMA table_info(table-name);` as explained in [the SQLite PRAGMA documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info).

I don't know of any way to get tablename|columnname returned as the result of a single query. I don't believe SQLite supports this. Your best bet is probably to use the two methods together to return the information you're looking for - first get the list of tables using sqlite_master, then loop through them to get their columns using PRAGMA table_info().

Comment: `pragma` doesn't give column data. `.schema` does, and I pasted its result in the question already. I'm already aware of that. I'm looking for a way.

Comment: Actually, `PRAGMA table_info()` does return column data, as long as you've got the table name, which you can get from sqlite_master. I do realize, though, that you're looking for a one-step solution returning only tablename|columname, whereas I was suggesting a workaround that could be used within a program of some sort (two steps). And while my answer hasn't really introduced any new information, I believe that it might help somebody. AFAIK there's no better way... Sorry. But I wouldn't mind being proven mistaken :-)

Comment: my bad. yes `pragma` gives that but if I have 100 tables, first I should get table list from `sqlite_master` and then I'm supposed to execute 100 `pragma` requests, which I don't want to.

Comment: Yes that it what it means, you need to use a combination of sqlite_master and prama table_info; this is the correct approach.

Comment: This answer gives you a dump of the schema, not the requested `tablename|columnName`. It turns out the `table_info` pragma is joinable, so it's a simple select: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160348/1268016

Answer (score 29):

Recent versions of SQLite allow you to [select against PRAGMA results now](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragfunc), which makes this easy:

```sql
SELECT 
  m.name as table_name, 
  p.name as column_name
FROM 
  sqlite_master AS m
JOIN 
  pragma_table_info(m.name) AS p
WHERE
  m.type = 'table' 
ORDER BY 
  m.name, 
  p.cid
```

where `p.cid` holds the column order of the CREATE TABLE statement, zero-indexed.

David Garoutte answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50548508/1268016), but this SQL should execute faster, and columns are ordered by the schema, not alphabetically.

Note that `table_info` also contains

- `type` (the datatype, like `integer` or `text`),
- `notnull` (`1` if the column has a `NOT NULL` constraint)
- `dflt_value` (`NULL` if no default value)
- `pk` (`0` if the column is not the table's primary key, `1` if it's the first primary key, and for composite primary keyed tables, `2` or larger values, based on key ordinal)

RTFM: https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

Comment: Note that `pk` is the primary key index. For tables with one column in the primary key, then that column `pk` value will be `1` (as the answer states). However, if the primary key has multiple columns, the `pk` value can be `2`, `3` and so on.

Comment: This has great unhappiness (i.e. raises errors) for non-table objects. Add `where m.type = 'table'` to fix.

Answer (score 12):

There are ".tables" and ".schema [table_name]" commands which give kind of a separated version to the result you get from "select * from sqlite_master;"

There is also "pragma table_info([table_name]);" command to get a better result for parsing instead of a construction query:

```
sqlite> .tables
students
sqlite> .schema students
create table students(id INTEGER, name TEXT);
sqlite> pragma table_info(students);
0|id|INTEGER|0||0
1|name|TEXT|0||0
```

Hope, it helps to some extent...

Comment: But I think `.tables` is a shell-specific function right? I need to execute it from SQL interface.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. In any case, you need to implement a parser :)

Answer (score 4):

Another useful trick is to first get all the table names from sqlite_master.

Then for each one, fire off a query "select * from t where 1 = 0".   If you analyze the structure of the resulting query - depends on what language/api you're calling it from - you get a rich structure describing the columns.

In python

```
c = ...db.cursor()
c.execute("select * from t where 1=0");
c.fetchall();
print c.description;
```

Juraj

PS.  I'm in the habit of using 'where 1=0' because the record limiting syntax seems to vary from db to db.  Furthermore, a good database will optimize out this always-false clause.

The same effect, in SQLite, is achieved with 'limit 0'.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if you're using .Net you can use the `DbConnection.GetSchema` method to retrieve information that usually is in INFORMATION_SCHEMA. If you have an abstraction layer you can have the same code for all types of databases (NOTE that MySQL seems to swich the 1st 2 arguments of the restrictions array).

Comment: Is this for SQLite? Which SQLite library for .NET is this? (not using .net but still want to know)

Comment: If you check the www.sqlite.org website, you'll see in their download section that they provide Precompiled Binaries For .NET at System.Data.SQLite.org, so it's the "official" ADO.NET adapter for SQLite.

Comment: SQlite does not support .GetSchema, throws a not support exception.

Comment: to go through .net utilities, you probably need to download a NuGet package

Answer (score 2):

Try this sqlite table schema parser, I implemented the sqlite table parser for parsing the table definitions in PHP.

It returns the full definitions (unique, primary key, type, precision, not null, references, table constraints... etc)

https://github.com/maghead/sqlite-parser

The syntax follows sqlite create table statement syntax: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but because of the number of times it has been viewed we are adding to the question for the simple reason most of the answers tell you how to find the TABLE names in the SQLite Database 
WHAT DO YOU DO WHEN THE TABLE NAME IS NOT IN THE DATABASE ?
This is happening to our app because we are creating TABLES programmatically 
So the code below will deal with the issue when the TABLE is NOT in or created by the Database Enjoy

```
    public void toPageTwo(View view){

    if(etQuizTable.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Table Name\n\n"
                +"           OR"+"\n\nMake Table First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG 
   ).show();
        etQuizTable.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    NEW_TABLE = etQuizTable.getText().toString().trim();
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE 
   type='table'", null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
            arrTblNames.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();

    boolean matchFound = false;
    for(int i=0;i<arrTblNames.size();i++) {
        if(arrTblNames.get(i).equals(NEW_TABLE)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ManageTables.this, TableCreate.class 
   );
            startActivity( intent );
            matchFound = true;
        }
    }
    if (!matchFound) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Such Table\n\n"
                +"           OR"+"\n\nMake Table First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG 
 ).show();
        etQuizTable.requestFocus();
    }
}
```