# Can I add a note to the SQLite table design using DB Browser for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

Is there a possibility to add notes in DB Browser for SQLite to annotate the table?

Comment: You can have comments in CREATE TABLE etc. statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB Browser for SQLite does not preserve comments used in a CREATE TABLE statement. As @Shawn commented, you can use comments in CREATE TABLE from command line sqlite3. [This (old) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426205/sqlite-adding-comments-to-tables-and-columns/7426289#7426289) gives example.