# Is there a way to add arbitrary text (eg a prompt or help text) to a column in a SQLite schema?

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database which expects user input for each column, so I need to have a prompt for each column and a short help text. The only way I can see to code this is by using the DEFAULT value for each column, but that is not what DEFAULT is for and could lead to unwanted consequences. I could define two more columns for each actual column and pre=populate them with text, but that seems a very heavy-handed approach. Or I could have a totally separate data structure with the column names as keys to access the text.

Is there a neat way to store text for each column in the schema itself?

Concrete example. I have accepted your answer below. Here is an example. I have over 40 tables such as:

CREATE TABLE Person (
PERSON_ID       TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
FAMILY_NAME     TEXT,
GIVEN_NAME_S    TEXT,
DATE_OF_BIRTH   TEXT,
DATE_OF_DEATH   TEXT
);

To get user input for PERSON_ID or FAMILY_NAME I would prompt, say::

"PROMPT": "What is this person's archive name?"
"HELP1": "A short name or tag which is unique in the archive, eg Marc2."

"PROMPT":"What is this person's family name?"
"HELP1":"The birth name this person inherited, eg Smith."

How can I store such text in the CREATE TABLE?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Example added to post above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sqlite: adding COMMENT ON descriptions to tables and columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426205/sqlite-adding-comment-on-descriptions-to-tables-and-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a SQLite database which expects user input for each column

As a rule of thumb, if you need to treat columns the same way (prompt1, prompt2, prompt3, ...) then you probably need to pivot the table. Turn those columns into rows.

You need two tables. One for the prompts, and one for the user's answers.

```
create table users (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table prompts (
  id integer primary key,
  prompt text not null,
  help text
);

create table answers (
  user_id integer not null
    references users
    on delete cascade,
  prompt_id integer not null
    references prompts
    on delete cascade,
  answer text not null,

  -- assuming a user can only answer each prompt once
  unique(user_id, prompt_id)
);
```

Comment: @NormanofAnstruther Thank you. I see you probably don't need the answers table as the answers will be stored directly in the appropriate table (ie. if you ask what their given name is, you'll store it in users.given_name). If the prompts are all about specific columns, you could add table and column name columns to prompts so you can automatically associate a prompt with the table & column to store the answer in. Alternatively,  if you're using an ORM/MVC where one table = one model class, the prompts could all be stored in the model class. Or they could be stored in the controller class.