# How to fetch data stored by SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I am trying to establish a connection between SQL server and SQLite C interface.  SQL stores data in **.MDF** and **.LOG** file-extension.

Is there any possiblility to fetch schema, data from above file extension?

Comment: Take a look at [**SQLite Schema Information Metadata**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460671/sqlite-schema-information-metadata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot import SQL Server data files into SQLite, as those are totally unrelated products and store data in different formats.

You can, however, export your database as SQL and import that into SQLite. Note, however, that both databases use slightly different SQL dialects, so you may have to correct generated SQL files by hand before thay can be imported into SQLite.

Comment: Do you mean exporting SQL database schema or data?

Comment: You have to export both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515969/exporting-data-in-sql-server-as-insert-into

Answer (score 2):

"We all know that SQLite is In memory database" is not true.
At the opposite is based on files.
anyway to get a nice example You can see at:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm