# How do you tell if a particular column is in a table?

Tags: sqlite, data-dictionary

I would like to know what query to use to determine if a particular table column exists in a given table.

For example I would like to know if the column named Address_1 exists in the table named Visits.

I think it is in a data dictionary table maybe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Edit: As pointed out by @tidwall, this answer is for SQL Server and won't work for sqlite. [This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604939/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-a-columns-in-a-table-for-a-sqlite-database) has the right answer for sqlite.**

---

```
SELECT name
FROM sysobjects
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM syscolumns
    WHERE name = 'THE_COLUMN_NAME'
)
```

also, this yields all the table column information for your parsing enjoyment:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```

Comment: I tried the first query but I get a "no such table exists" error so I will try the other statement using the Count(*) function which should be as good for me.

Comment: @vzwick: This question is for SQLite, not SQL Server. `syscolumns` does not exist in SQLite. The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604939/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-a-columns-in-a-table-for-a-sqlite-database).

Comment: @tidwall Thanks for the pointer, updated the answer accordingly.