# How to get 'NOT NULL' from sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table in sqlite3

```
CREATE TABLE exhibit(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT NOT NULL, 
    text1 TEXT NOT NULL, 
    text2 TEXT, 
    text3 TEXT, 
    photo TEXT, 
    audio TEXT, 
    video TEXT, 
    location TEXT NOT NULL);
```

And I have this code for getting types and names of columns:

```
def get_columns(obj):
    con = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')

    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        obj.__str__
        sql_req = 'PRAGMA table_info('+obj+');'
        cur.execute(sql_req)
        data = cur.fetchall()
        result1 = []
        result2 = []
        for d in data:
            result1.append(d[1])
            result2.append(d[2])

        result = []
        result.append(result1)
        result.append(result2)
        #print(result)
        if len(result1)>0:
            return(1, result)
```

But in my program I need to know if the type is "NOT NULL" or not.
How can I get it?
I`m a newcomer in programing and I have no idea:(
Please, help

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604939/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-a-columns-in-a-table-for-a-sqlite-database) about getting information about a table and its columns.